Ошибка преобразования из PDF в DOCX. Python
При преобразовании из PDF в DOCX файл нечитаем. Я конвертирую через tabula. Я также пробовал через pdf2docx, также нечитаемый текст.
    import tabula
    from docx import Document
    
    tables = tabula.read_pdf(input_path='2.pdf',
                             pages='all')
    doc = Document()
    for table in tables:
        doc.add_table(rows=len(table),
                      cols=len(table.columns),
                      style='Table Grid')
        for i, row in enumerate(table.iterrows()):
            for j, value in enumerate(row[1]):
                doc.tables[-1].cell(i, j).text = str(value)
    
        doc.add_paragraph()
    
    doc.save('123.docx')

